# UICollectionViewCell double size on selection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I currently have a UICollectionView that is 2 columns of UICollectionViewCells, and I am wondering if someone has determined how to make a cell expands to the full width of the screen  and make the others move down. I have attempted to mess with the cell's frame size and the rows, but nothing seems to behave properly at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.path = indexPath;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.path]) {
        return CGSizeMake(320, 150);
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(150, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost, except when the item on the right is selected, the item on the left sits in the center rather then everything shifting to make room for it. Also, is there a way to animate that?

Comment: @user1933131, where do you want that left one to go when you select the right one? Do you want it to stay on the left and have a hole on the right? I don't know if there's a way to animate that.

Answer (score 0):

You need two UICollectionViewLayouts. Change your itemSize on the second UICollectionViewLayout. Then you can call `setCollectionViewLayout:animated` which will animate the change between the two collection view layouts.